# Please explain tech.lef , tech.lib

Tags: asic, eda, vlsi, physical-design

Can anyone explain what is in the `tech.lef` and  `tech lib` files? Which stage of PNR (Place and Route) are they used for? Are these things provided by the foundry or the EDA vendor?

Comment: Why did this get voted down with no comment? It is an important question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technology file contains the physical properties of your fabrication process. For example, it would contain the number of metal layers, the design rules, resistances, capacitances, as well as the routing grid needed. This file is specific to the process used, so it would be supplied by the foundry or your gate library vendor. If there are multiple process options (e.g. multiple metal stacks) you would need to select the correct tech file. Usually the file extension for a tech file is `.tf`.

A `.lef` (Library Exchange Format) file can contain the same information as a technology file. This can be supplied by the foundry, but it can also be generated from the technology file if you only have the technology file. You can also use a `.lef` file to store the physical data of a gate or macro library.

Library (`.lib` and `.db`) files are usually logical, timing and electrical characteristics of a gate or macro library. These are necessary to synthesize a design, and also necessary for the place and route tool (and static timing analysis in general) to function. These files are provided by your gate library vendor, or the foundry if they supply the gate library.

These are basically required at the beginning of the place and route phase in order to configure your tool for the process.

Comment: tech.lef and .tf ( technology file ) contains information's  like pitch, routing direction , spacing ...etc about different layers (metal , base layers) . So which file the PnR tool read as reference to routing ? From which file the values like pitch , metal spacing are coming from ?

Comment: @GIRIMURALI From what I've seen, you have the option of selecting which one you want to use. If you have both, (and they are equivalent), I would pick one and just use that one.

Comment: For routing there's a third source of data: The routing track definition. Depending on the tool vendor there are different ways to set this. The technology files (tlef/tf) define what's possible, while the actual track definition file defines how you'd like your routing to be done. Sometimes foundries deliver them. If it's missing default (usually minwidth/minspacing) pitch is used.

Answer (score 3):

These files are provided from your standard cell library provider. It may be the foundry or a third party vendor.

**The .LEF** file(s) describe the metal rules and cell geometries. Usually they are split into at least two files. One file is typically to describe metal rules for things like routing and via placement and spacing. The second type of LEF file describes the geometry of the standard cells. So each cell, nand2, nor3, etc. have metal polygons which are stored in this file. The LEF files are necessary for placement, routing and design rule checking. The tech LEF should be from the foundry and the standard cell LEF should be from the standard cell provider.

**The .LIB** file(s) describe the timing of the standard cells. Usually there are several files for different process corners and operating conditions. They are necessary for best/worst or MMMC timing analysis.